# Удалить из массива JS элементы на основании другого массива

Tags: javascript

Есть ли способ (желательно, без циклов), удалить из массива А значения, содержащиеся в массиве Б?

Comment: `arr1.filter(item => !arr2.includes(item))`? Но это создаёт новый массив. Нужно именно удалить из имеющегося?

Comment: Подойдёт и новый массив, только не работает - при попытке убрать из 390 значений 4, получаю всё равно 390. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Странно, должно. Приведите пример данных, на которых не работает. Какой тип у элементов массива? Только не все 390 значений. Приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно сделать с [сетом](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arr2 = [1, 2, 4];

const s = new Set(arr2);
console.log(arr1.filter(e => !s.has(e)));
```

P.S. Т.к. сложность поиска в Set О(1), то целый алгоритм имеет cложность О(n).

```js
const arr1 = [{ a:1 }, { a:2 }, { a:3 }, { a:4 }, { a:5 }];
const arr2 = [{ a:1 }, { a:2 }, { a:4 }];

const s = new Set(arr2.map(e => JSON.stringify(e)));
console.log(arr1.filter(e => !s.has(JSON.stringify(e))));
```

P.P.S `JSON.stringify` не самый лучший вариант использовать здесь. Я просто показал дял примера. Нам надо проверить объекты на соответствие всех полей. Можете использовать [этот метод](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32922084/7791165).

Comment: Не работает. Возможна ли проблема быть в том, что оба -  массивы объектов, а не простых чисел?

Comment: там показывать нечего, 


vm.arr = result; // приходит из сервиса, Array из объектов, описываются в классе на бэке

const s = new Set(arr);
var tenants = arr1.filter(e => !s.has(e)); // arr1 - те же объекты, полученные ранее, с бэка.

Типы объектов друг другу соответствуют

Comment: Различий быть не должно, оба масива приходят с бэка и оба описываются общим классом

Comment: Тем не менее, решение с JSON.stringify оказалось верным. Код работает, всё хорошо. Искренне благодарю за помощь!

Comment: @kEdo, пожалуйста

Comment: @kEdo имейте в виду, что если вдруг в `result` придет `[{a : 1, b : 2}]`, а в `arr1` будет `[{b : 2, a : 1}]`, то `JSON.stringify` уже не поможет.

Comment: @Yaant Эта тема использовалась для фильтрации одногого списка на основании другого. Данные взяты из одного источника, и если в списке на фильтрацию есть объект, то он 100% будет абсолютно таким же в исходном массиве. Но благодарю за уточнение!

Answer (score 6):

Так можно черех [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
let b = [6,7,10];

let c = a.reduce( (acc, item) => {
                    if (!b.includes(item)) acc.push(item); 
                  return acc;} , []);
                  
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант через регулярные выражения:

```
let a = [...];
let b = [...];

let c = a.replace([b]/gi, '');
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: у массивов нет метода `replace`

Answer (score 0):

```
let filteredArray = array1.filter(function(item) {
  return !array2.includes(item);
});
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).